# Simulating a mouse pointer click (can move but can't click)

Tags: c#, mouseevent

I'm trying to simulate a left mouse pointer click (and a double click) at a certain position on the screen.

I have the following code:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

//This simulates a left mouse click
public static void LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos)
{
     SetCursorPos(xpos, ypos);
     mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
     mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
}
```

I am able to move the mouse pointer to the coordinates with the above code but I am unable to make the click happen (or a double click).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the wrong const. Taken from pinvoke.net :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

[Flags]
public enum MouseEventFlags
{
    LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002,
    LEFTUP = 0x00000004,
    MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020,
    MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040,
    MOVE = 0x00000001,
    ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000,
    RIGHTDOWN = 0x00000008,
    RIGHTUP = 0x00000010
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

public static void LeftClick(int x, int y)
{
    SetCursorPos(x, y);
    mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: *Cursor*`.Position = new System.Drawing.`*Point*`(x, y);` is giving a context error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. Let me edit your answer. Thank you!